# How to make a new function that includes a template

Tags: functions, templates

I am adding social share buttons to all of my posts.  Is there a way to put the code into a function so I can just call that function when I went to put the social share buttons somewhere?

This is the social share buttons code...

```html
                <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/social-twitter.png"></a>

                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook."><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/social-facebook.png"></a>

                <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/social-pinterest.png"></a>

                <a href="http://www.bloglovin.com/e/?b=' .get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '&#038;p=' .get_permalink().'&#038;t='.get_the_title().'"onclick=\'window.open(this.href,&quot;bloglovin_like&quot;,&quot;height=320,width=480,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0&quot;); return false;\'--><img style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/social-bloglovin-1.png" alt="" />

                <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/social-shopping.png"></a>
```

Here is my frontage.php I want to put the social share buttons before the Read More button of each post.  However if I placed the social share code before each of these I would have to paste in the code quite a few times.  So I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this? (I know I already have a few functions in this code - that is because I had help some help creating this code - I'm still new to this and can't quite figure out exactly how to do this on my own)

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => 1
] );
<div id="ajax">
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
            <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-12' ); ?>>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>

            <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-thumbnail' ); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
    </article>
<?php 
        }
        $i++;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    </div>
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
<?php load_more_button(); ?>
get_footer();
```

This is the layout of the front page
[image]

Comment: This isn't related to the question per se, but why are  the `<article class="post col-md-4">` blocks repeated over and over?

Comment: I've updated my original question.  It's used for my layout.  I have a row of one post and then two rows of 3 posts, repeat.

Comment: You should control the layout with conditional logic. The code posted will repeat the same post a bunch of times; it's not necessary to repeat those article sections over and over.

Comment: I know you already answered my original question (thank you so much!) would you mind helping me with this?  Or pointing me in the right direction on how to correct this?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an updated version of the template code. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your share button html to a template file in your theme:

**your-theme/share-buttons.php**

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/social-twitter.png"></a>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook."><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/social-facebook.png"></a>

<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/social-pinterest.png"></a>

<a href="http://www.bloglovin.com/e/?b=' .get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '&#038;p=' .get_permalink().'&#038;t='.get_the_title().'"onclick=\'window.open(this.href,&quot;bloglovin_like&quot;,&quot;height=320,width=480,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0&quot;); return false;\'--><img style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/social-bloglovin-1.png" alt="" />

<a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/social-shopping.png"></a>
```

Use [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) to include the template in the appropriate locations.

```
get_template_part( 'share-buttons' );
```

**Edit:** Here's an updated version of the template code which should address some issues in the original. It includes the share buttons template part too:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => 1
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and after every block of 6 posts... ?>

            <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-12' ); ?>>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>

            <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-thumbnail' ); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article><?php 
        }
        $i++;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}

get_footer();
```

Comment: Would I include the get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); right before my  <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> if I wanted the buttons to appear just before the Read more link?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! Just to be clear it should be wrapped in PHP tags: `<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome, user6738171!

Comment: @DaveRomsey Can't we use a short code instead of `get_template_part()`?

Comment: @Ranuka, sure you *could* but that's not how I would approach it. Sharing buttons are something that I'd want to appear automatically without the user having to remember to place the shortcode. There are a ton of ways to go about this though.

Comment: @DaveRomsey Hi Dave. I added the "Easy Load More" plugin to my front-page.php and have updated my original code to reflect the new div wrappers, and placing the load more button at the bottom of my 14 posts and then loading another 14 posts.  Unfortanetly the page is producing an error, do you see where I went wrong?

Comment: Hi! Remove the `<?php ?>` tags surrounding `load_more_button();`. You're already inside of PHP tags so adding them again is breaking things. Make sure  error reporting is turned on. Please post a new question if things are acting up still from there.